# Java JVM or Eclipse Start-up Overhead

Tags: java, eclipse, performance, profiling

I have a network threaded application that I run under Eclipse (Indigo) and Javd 1.7x.  For quite a while I have have noticed that the first run of the application produced front and end loaded degradation in performance, for example if I was to load up the application and and then hit it (using a test harness) with say 100 network packets the first few responses would be heavily erratic and the last few. [edit] Without unloading the application, and just running the test harness again, the application performs normally.[end edit]

I decided to get to try and get to the bottom of it and loaded up VisualVM 1.3.5 to profile the behaviour.  The CPU Usage has a distinct spike going from 10% to over 50% at the beginning of the run.  After the spikes, everything appears normal, and as stated above subsequent runs do not have the leading spikes in CPU Utilisation and the profile of subsequent runs is identical to the profile between the spikes of the first run.   There doesn't appear to be any evidence that the number of threads is causing it, but there is a small rise.  Heap space increases from 100MB to 200MB, but other than that everything appears normal.

Any thoughts would be welcome.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think you would get any useful replies unless you post your code and ask specific questions sir!!

Answer (score 0):

Its fairly typical for system performance to be erratic the first time you run a test.  This is due to the operating system reading libraries, JAR files, and other data off of disk and storing it in cache.  Once this has been done that first time all subsequent runs will be much faster and more consistent.

Also, keep in mind that the JVM will also tend to be slower right after it starts up.  Due to its hotspot analysis and just-in-time compiling, the code will need to run a little while before the JVM optimizes the byte code for your particular workload.

Answer (score 0):

This is typical for OSGi environments, where bundles may be initialize lazily upon first access of a bundles class or services.

You can figure out if this is the case in your scenario by starting eclipse with `-console -consolelog` arguments.

When the console opens and the application was loaded, issue the `ss` command and note which bundles are marked LAZY. Then, run your test, issue `ss` again, and see if one of the LAZY bundles now became ACTIVE. If so, you can force eager start of your bundles via the configuration/config.ini file. This can also be accomplished via the [IStartup](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/IStartup.html) extension point.

Comment: I suspect that this is on the right track, but adding the osgi.compatibility.eagerStart.LazyActivation has not helped, and there are so many classes marked as <<LAZY>> makes it difficult.   I have noticed that the actual CPU spike appears to be a single class that loads that causes a GC cycle.  It is this cycle, I believe, that is causing the erratic first run performance.